# how to create new data frame from the output of value_counts()

Tags: pandas, seaborn, pandas-groupby, pandas-datareader

i have a dataframe name 'df' and i run below code...

```
df['Station'].value_counts()
```

my Output will be:

```
Station 308A   -   3955

Station 329   -    3905

Station 313   -    2963

.....................

Station 381   -    2383
```

**Name: Station, dtype: int64**

Now i want to plot this in countplot:

```
sns.countplot(x= "Station", data=df['Station'].value_counts().head(30), palette="bright")
```

gives me error!!!

because i can only pass dataframe in Data ex: `data=df`

**So my question i want output of this line df['Station'].value_counts() as a new data frame**

so that i can directly pass it as `sns(data=new_df)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter top values by parameter `order` with `value_counts` and `index`:

```
np.random.seed(34345)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Station':np.random.randint(100, size=1000)}).astype(str).radd('station')
print (df.head())
     Station
0  station28
1  station48
2  station48
3  station61
4  station30

N = 5
sns.countplot(x='Station', 
              data=df, 
              palette="bright",
              order=df['Station'].value_counts().index[:N])
```

Comment: i got data new dataframe df1, than i passed x= 'Station' i see no count values ploted in my graph also tried with 'Index' same result

Comment: @Shiva_Achari - so need `sns.countplot(x="Station", data=df, palette="bright")` ?

Comment: in my countplot, all the .head(30) station  has value 1 ,

Comment: there are 500 different station.... i wanted to plot only top 20 or top 30 which has highest count values...

Comment: @Shiva_Achari - Please check now.

Comment: yes it worked,by setting  order=df['Station'].value_counts().iloc[:N].index

Answer (score 0):

You can also create new Dataframe using `count_values()` but then instead of `sns.countplot()`, it should be `sns.barplot()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Station': np.random.randint(10, size=10)})
df['Station'] = 'station'+df['Station'].astype('str')

value_count = df['Station'].value_counts()
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Station': value_count.index, 'Values': value_count.values})

# df1.head(3) will select top 3 rows
sns.barplot(x= "Station",y='Values', data=df1.head(3), palette="bright")
```